# Format of page view messed up after upgrading to Bootstrap 3 in Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

In our rails 3.2 app, a snippet of code was used to set the width to `col-md-5` for input fields in simple_form (version 2.1.1.). Here is the code in `simple_form.rb` which is the initialize file for `gem simple_form`:

```
%w(StringInput RangeInput CollectionInput GroupedCollectionSelectInput PasswordInput TextInput NumericInput CollectionSelectInput).each do |class_name|
  old_class = "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{class_name}".constantize
  new_class = Class.new(old_class) do
    def input_html_classes
      super.push('col-md-5')
    end
  end
  Object.const_set(class_name, new_class)
end
```

Here is in bootstrap 3 `col-md-5` replaced `span5` in bootstrap 2. The problem is that the format of the page is messed up. Here is the page view (with messed up format) in 3.0:

[image]

Here is the page view in 2.0 which is the page supposed to be:

[image]

The only change we did was to replace `span5` with `col-md-5` for bootstrap 3.0 and we can not find why this change messes up with the page format. Is there something else we need to do for bootstrap upgrade?

UPDATE:
here is the html source code for the portion of messed up page (portion inserted as ajax):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>
            <a href="/authentify/view_handler?index=0" class="btn btn-primary" id="close">返回</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="/commonx/misc_definitions/new.js?for_which=quality_system&amp;subaction=quality_system" class="btn btn-primary" data-remote="true" id="new_log_link">新质量体系</a>   
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

The new.js inserts a page as below:

```
<div id="main_body">

 <h4><%=t('New ' + @for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize) %></h4>

<%= simple_form_for(@misc_definition) do |f| %>     
  <%= f.input :name, :label => t(@for_which.sub('_', ' ').titleize + ':') %>
  <%= f.input :brief_note, :label => t("Brief Note:"), :input_html => {:rows => 2} %> 
  <%= f.input :for_which, :input_html => {:value => @for_which}, :as => :hidden, :readonly => true %>
  <%= f.input :ranking_index, :label => t('Ranking Index'), :placehoder => '1, 2, 3 ...'%> 

  <%= link_to t('Back'), misc_definitions_path(:for_which => @for_which, :subaction => @for_which), :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('Save'), :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser)-ing your page and read [the official v2->v3 migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)

Comment: Please add the HTML generated for the form as well as the custom CSS for it(if any)

Comment: yeah, you've got no rows for your col's. You really want to do a proper install of simple_form-bootstrap `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

Comment: Please have a look at this link https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/857

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a standard bootstrap layout with your forms you could just generate the proper wrappers  via simple forms generator. Maybe you have to rename your simple_form.rb initializer before (to simple_form.rb.backup for example) and merge your configuration with the generated one if you have other things in there besides bootstrap config code.

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Comment: We are using Rails 3.2 which only works with simple_form 2.x. Only simple_form 3 supports bootstrap 3. So it seems that we still need to find a monkey patch for this width issue for simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you don't put rows.

The structure of Bootstrap is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```